# Python: slicing a very large binary file

Tags: python, binary, large-files

Say I have a binary file of 12GB and I want to slice 8GB out of the middle of it. I know the position indices I want to cut between.

How do I do this? Obviously 12GB won't fit into memory, that's fine, but 8GB won't either... Which I thought was fine, but it appears binary doesn't seem to like it if you do it in chunks! I was appending 10MB at a time to a new binary file and there are discontinuities on the edges of each 10MB chunk in the new file.

Is there a Pythonic way of doing this easily?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a quick example.  Adapt as needed:

```
def copypart(src, dest, start, length, bufsize=1024*1024):
    with open(src, 'rb') as f1:
        f1.seek(start)
        with open(dest, 'wb') as f2:
            while length:
                chunk = min(bufsize, length)
                data = f1.read(chunk)
                f2.write(data)
                length -= chunk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GIG = 2**30
    copypart('test.bin', 'test2.bin', 1 * GIG, 8 * GIG)
```

Comment: I did something very similar than this and it didn't seem to like it, with binary if you extract a block of data out of the middle can't it sometimes mess up at the edges as it needs its surrounding bytes to make sense? Hmm. I'll try your code though cheers. Also did you get your length and buffer the wrong way round in the last line of your code?

Comment: That is start and length...the last line uses the default for bufsize.  I'm not sure what you mean by "messes up at the edges".  If you need surrounding bytes maybe your start and length are incorrect?

Comment: You are correct! I had messed up myself, it all works now :) What's an optimum buffer size for file transfer then? 1MB good?

Comment: A different size may be faster or slower...the only way to know is to for sure is to profile.

Don't forget to accept an answer :^)